# Constants and Include files in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, include

Is it possible to include a set of 'constant' values in a TSQL stored procedure? I have a situation where I'm using an integer field to store bit values and I have small set of 'constant' values that I use to insert/select against that field

```
DECLARE @CostsCalculated int = 32
DECLARE @AggregatedCalculated int = 64

--Set CostCalculated bit
update MyTable set DataStatus = ISNULL(DataStatus, 0) | @CostsCalculated
where Id = 10

--How many rows have that bit set
select count(*) from MyTable where ISNULL(DataStatus, 0) & @CostsCalculated = @CostsCalculated
```

I could repeat the same set of DECLARES at the top of every SP but I'd rather include the code, which means I can change in one place as new bit values are added.

Comment: You can always store the constants in a table.

Comment: I'd still have to cut/paste boiler plate code into all my SPs or join to that table which'd be a nasty performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can't include constants like that.

How many constants are you talking about, though?  Instead of declared constants, I suppose you could create a function for each constant you want, and call the function instead of `@CostsCalculated`, but I'm not sure how realistic that is.

Alternately, store the values in a designated table.

Comment: +1: There isn't any functionality to support constants in SQL Server - has to be via function or table.  Stuff like this is why Oracle Packages are so awesome, and odd why no other database provides similar functionality.