# Is there a T-SQL equivalent for #include, and why

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Constants and Include files in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243139/constants-and-include-files-in-tsql)

I've been looking for a T-SQL equivalent of the C "#include" directive. As I haven't found, I wonder

- Is it possible that MS did not include any sort of SQL files inclusion / joined execution
- If not, why
- If not, is there any better way for me to execute several SQL files at once without copy-paste or manual precompilation

For those curious of my motivations, I am writing a set of similar queries, and I find it convenient to externalize constants (from enum tables), pre-computations (making some test input tables) and parameter variables (which subsets I'm working on).

As far as I know, I can't really use stored procedures or functions for that (And I don't like the idea of polluting my DB with those).

Comment: "Including" files is usually a feature of the SQL *client* being used, not of the actual SQL language/dialect. With `sqlcmd` it's the `-i` command that does this. Other clients have other commands for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Do you know any include feature for MS SQL studio 2008?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could look into executing in SQLCMD mode, either in SSMS or via sqlcmd utility (command line).  There is a `:r <file name>` command that allows you to include external files in the current execution session.  So if you included a `:r my_init_script.sql` near the top of your larger script it may achieve what you are after.

Note, this is for SQL 2005 and up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using stored procedures.  You'll be able to put many commands within each and use parameters to control them.  Also, you can call different stored procedures in series as necessary.  If you have a bunch of "constants", you can use a table to store them, and select them as necessary.